# Clustering points based on their function values and proximity

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cluster-analysis

I have many points `X` and their function values `f` stored in `numpy` arrays. I want to find **all points** in `X` that don't have a better point (smaller `f` value) within a distance `r`.

`X` is hundreds of thousands of points, so I can't precompute `sp.spatial.distance.pdist(X)` but resort to the following:

```
def cluster(X,f,r):
    pts,n = np.shape(X)
    centers = []
    for i in range(0,pts):
        pdist = sp.spatial.distance.cdist(X,[X[i]])
        if not np.any(np.logical_and(pdist <= r, f < f[i])):
            centers.append(i)
    return centers
```

This takes minutes. Is there a way to quickly cluster based on proximity and another metric?

Comment: 5.19 to 3.82 is a 25% reduction, which wouldn't say "isn't that much faster".  If you can amortize the cost of sorting, it can be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can significantly reduce the number of distance computation by keeping a record. For instance, if j is a neighbor of a center i and it has a larger f value, then j can never be a center since one of its neighbors is i which has a smaller f value. Please check the following and let me know if you need clarification.

```
def cluster4(X,f,r):
    pts,n = np.shape(X)
    centers = np.ones((pts,1),dtype=int)
    for i in range(pts):
        if not centers[i]:
            continue
        pdist = sp.spatial.distance.cdist(X,[X[i]])
        inrange = (pdist <= r)
        inrange[i] = False
        lesser = (f < f[i])
        if np.any(inrange & lesser):
            centers[i] = 0
        centers[inrange & np.invert(lesser)] = 0
    return np.where(centers == 1)[0]
```

Comment: Sorting 500,000 points with this approach reduced the computation time from 28 seconds of brute force 0.06 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

You could partition the space so that you could ignore partitions wholly outside the radius for the point being tested.

You could also order the points by f, so you don't need to scan those with smaller values.

Comment: Ordering the points by `f` is slightly faster. See **Edit 1**. I am hoping for something even faster, perhaps by vectorizing the cdist calculation without requiring to store it all. All of the points are within a box, so it seems like "partitioning the space" would require as much computational effort.

Comment: You could buy better hardware :)

Answer (score 1):

I think one can sum this up as:

Use k-nearest neighbor to build a kdtree. Query the tree for points close to your query point with radius, check their function values.

```
x=scipy.random.rand(10000,2) # sample data
f = exp(-x[:,0]**2) # sample function values
K=scipy.spatial.KDTree(x) # generate kdtree of data set
ix = K.query_point_ball(x[0],0.1) # query indices of points within 0.1 of x[0] in euclidean norm
# check f[ix] for your function criterion
```

You can query for all points at once if you are interested in that

```
ix = K.query_point_ball(x,0.04)
```

Comment: This is significantly slower than the original approach. See the **Edit 2**